# Installing Ubuntu, messed up boot menu

Tags: 16.04

I'm beginner with programming and computers and I wanted to reinstall Ubuntu. I falsly believed I have to hold `F2` key insted of `F12` when computer starts to reinstall OS. Some menu poped up and I obviously clicked wrong things...I successfuly instaled Ubuntu 16.04 and message poped up saying that I have to restart. But, when I restart same black screen appears(that started after I clicked some stuff after pressing F2). It first shows in upper left corner `Checking media`, then after some seconds(about a minute)next three screens appear sequentially:
[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R09jX.jpg), [second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM0Zn.jpg) and [third](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI26k.jpg).
When I have bootable USB inserted this USB becomes first thing on list in picture three(I installed Ubuntu by pressing `Enter` on it).
I need this laptop tomorrow and can't fix it myself. Any help would be grately appreciated!

I also have no idea where to post question like this, so I apologize if it's in wrong place!

EDIT:
If I manualy restart computer with special key for that I get to [this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmErp.jpg). I tried to set setting to `Default settings` but my system still doesn't notice my already installed Ubuntu by starting it, unless I want to reintall uUbuntu in which case it asks me if I want to install this same Ubuntu along side alredy installed one.

Comment: This is the right place. 

Start your PC & bring the menu you brought by pressing F2. Press F9, select yes in any dialouge box. Then press F10, again select yes in any dialouge box. See if it works..

Comment: Thanks for help. In situation I described abovethis doesn't work as F1-F12 do not work. But I manually restarted my computer and got to menu described above in EDIT.